# Python Sierpinski Triangle

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I am trying to make a Sierpinski triangle with small triangles of color Green.
But I am getting wrong output as shown in the pic.

Can someone help me in correcting my code?

A Sierpinski triangle (in black) looks like the following.  My screenshot is below the code.

[image: Sierpinski triangle]

```
import turtle

    def draw_triangle(some_turtle):
        #This for loop will create - Outer Triangle
        some_turtle.color("green")
        some_turtle.begin_fill()
        for i in range(1,4):
            some_turtle.forward(50)
            some_turtle.left(120)
            #This for loop will create - Inner Triangle
            for j in range(1,4):    
                some_turtle.forward(25)
                some_turtle.left(120)
                some_turtle.end_fill()

    def draw_art():     
        window = turtle.Screen()
        window.bgcolor("white")
        #Create the turtle Brad - Draws a Triangle
        brad = turtle.Turtle()
        brad.shape("arrow")
        brad.color("green")
        brad.speed(50)
        #This for loop will create - Inner & Outer Triangle At 120 deg
        for d in range(1,4):
            brad.left(120)
            #This for loop will create - Inner & Outer Triangle At distance 50 
            for c in range(1,5):
                draw_triangle(brad)
                brad.forward(50)
    window.exitonclick()
    draw_art()
```

[image: Screenshot]

[image: unfilled S. triangle]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lBbZx.jpg)

Comment: You need to narrow down your question. Fixing the code isn't a good one.

Comment: I have added another image and the output should look like that image

Comment: Serpinski's triangle tends to be a lot easier to draw using recursion.

Comment: yes.. I know but I want to do it with out recursion method and the only issue is how do I use the color function in a loop..

Comment: I have added pic 3 which which tells that the code is working and I am getting the triangle but not able to color them

Comment: You have nine calls to `end_fill` for each call to `begin_fill`, which doesn't make sense.

Comment: @interjay: - I know the the code for begin_fill() and end_fill() is wrong. I am struggling to where should I place them in a loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several problems with the code you posted, besides the `begin_fill()` and `end_fill()` being in the wrong places: you call `exitonclick()` before `draw_art()` so your program shouldn't run at all; you reference `window` from a scope in which it's not defined; the argument to `speed()` doesn't make much sense based on the documentation.

The following rework addresses the above issues and some style tweaks:

```
import turtle

def draw_triangle(some_turtle):
    # This for loop will create - Outer Triangle
    for i in range(3):
        some_turtle.forward(50)
        some_turtle.left(120)
        # This for loop will create - Inner Triangle
        some_turtle.begin_fill()
        for j in range(3):
            some_turtle.forward(25)
            some_turtle.left(120)
        some_turtle.end_fill()

def draw_art():
    # Create the turtle Brad - Draws a Triangle
    brad = turtle.Turtle(shape="arrow")
    brad.color("green")
    brad.speed("fastest")

    # This for loop will create - Inner & Outer Triangle At 120 deg
    for d in range(3):
        brad.left(120)
        # This for loop will create - Inner & Outer Triangle At distance 50
        for c in range(4):
            draw_triangle(brad)
            brad.forward(50)

    brad.hideturtle()

window = turtle.Screen()
window.bgcolor("white")

draw_art()

window.exitonclick()
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

If you still don't get the above image, here's something to consider:  the turtle/tkinter fill logic varies between Unix and Windows systems when it comes to filling areas that are already filled.  Your basic algorithm redraws, and refills, many of the triangles.  So, if you're still having problems, look into changing the code to only draw, and fill, each triangle only once.  Something like the following rework which doesn't duplicate the drawing of the corners like your original:

```
def draw_triangle(some_turtle):
    # This for loop will create - Outer Triangle
    for i in range(3):
        # This for loop will create - Inner Triangle
        some_turtle.begin_fill()
        for j in range(3):
            some_turtle.forward(25)
            some_turtle.left(120)
        some_turtle.end_fill()
        some_turtle.forward(50)
        some_turtle.left(120)

def draw_art():
    # Create the turtle Brad - Draws a Triangle
    brad = turtle.Turtle(shape="arrow")
    brad.color("green")
    brad.speed("fastest")

    # This for loop will create - Inner & Outer Triangle At 120 deg
    for d in range(3):
        brad.left(120)
        brad.forward(50)
        # This for loop will create - Inner & Outer Triangle At distance 50
        for c in range(3):
            draw_triangle(brad)
            brad.forward(50)

    brad.hideturtle()
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the solution.

Comment: There were two mistakes in my code: 1) begin_fill() was at the wrong location 2) The indentation of "some_turtle.end_fill()" was not done properly after for loop.Once I fixed these two issues it worked...Thank you so much again.Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

Your `begin_fill`s and `end_fill`s are not at the right place.  Begin filling at the top of your outer for loop, and end filling at the bottom of it.

In other words, make this your draw_triangle function:

```
def draw_triangle(some_turtle):
    #This for loop will create - Outer Triangle
    some_turtle.color("green")
    for i in range(1,4):
        some_turtle.begin_fill()
        some_turtle.forward(50)
        some_turtle.left(120)
        #This for loop will create - Inner Triangle
        for j in range(1,4):    
            some_turtle.forward(25)
            some_turtle.left(120)
        some_turtle.end_fill()
```

Note the difference in the placement of the `begin_fill` and `end_fill`

Comment: note carefully the indenting for the end_fill. It moved from your original.

Answer (score 0):

```
import turtle
    t=turtle.Turtle()
    def f(a,b):
        #a=the distance that need to go, b how many triangle in side the large triangle
        if b==0:
            return 

        else:
            for i in range(3):
                t.forward(a)
                t.left(120)
                f(a/2,b-1)
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow! Please edit your answer to add some text explaining how this solves the question.